# Wpf Canvas not getting out of border

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

c# code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;
namespace Attempt
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Ellipse e1 = new Ellipse();
        DispatcherTimer t1, t2, t3, t4, t5;
        TimeSpan o = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10);
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            t1 = new DispatcherTimer();
            t2 = new DispatcherTimer();
            t3 = new DispatcherTimer();
            t4 = new DispatcherTimer();
            t1.Interval = o;
            t2.Interval = o;
            t3.Interval = o;
            t4.Interval = o;
            t1.Tick += T1_Tick;
            t2.Tick += T2_Tick;
            t3.Tick += T3_Tick;
            t4.Tick += T4_Tick;
            myCanvas.Children.Add(e1);
            e1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            Canvas.SetLeft(e1, 250);
            Canvas.SetTop(e1, 250);
            e1.Height = 75;
            e1.Width = 75;
            this.KeyDown += MainWindow_KeyDown;
            if(Canvas.GetLeft(e1) + e1.Width > myCanvas.Width)
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(e1, myCanvas.Width);
            }
        }


        //Key.Right
        private void T4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            Canvas.SetLeft(e1, Canvas.GetLeft(e1) + 10);
        }


        //Key.Left
        private void T3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            Canvas.SetLeft(e1, Canvas.GetLeft(e1) - 10);
        }


        //Key.Up
        private void T2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            Canvas.SetTop(e1, Canvas.GetTop(e1) - 10);
        }


        //Key.Down
        private void T1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            Canvas.SetTop(e1, Canvas.GetTop(e1) + 10);
        }


        //Shortcut
        public void timer1()
        {
            t1.Start();
            t2.Stop();
            t3.Stop();
            t4.Stop();
        }
        public void timer2()
        {
            t1.Stop();
            t2.Start();
            t3.Stop();
            t4.Stop();
        }
        public void timer3()
        {
            t1.Stop();
            t2.Stop();
            t3.Start();
            t4.Stop();
        }
        public void timer4()
        {
            t1.Stop();
            t2.Stop();
            t3.Stop();
            t4.Start();
        }
        //MainWindow KeyDown
        private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            if (e.Key == Key.Down && !t2.IsEnabled) 
            {
                timer1();
            }
            if (e.Key == Key.Up && !t1.IsEnabled)
            {
                timer2();
            }
            if (e.Key == Key.Left && !t4.IsEnabled)
            {
                timer3();
            }
            if (e.Key == Key.Right && !t3.IsEnabled)
            {
                timer4();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

xaml code :

```
<Window x:Class="Attempt.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Attempt"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Canvas Name="myCanvas">

    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

I was attempting to create a little movement "game" where you can move to all 4 sides (blocking reverse sides) and I am try to make it not be able to hit the canvas.
For some reason it doesn't read anything of what I am trying to do (This part) :

```
    if(Canvas.GetLeft(e1) + e1.Width > myCanvas.Width)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(e1, myCanvas.Width);
    }
```

Where am I going wrong? Is there something wrong with the way I handle it?
Thanks.
(Been trying to solve this for the last hour and a half and I have no idea.. thanks.)

Comment: Why do you have four timers, instead of just storing the current direction and move the Ellipse in a single timer's Tick event? Besides that, what exactly doesn't work? Isn't the Ellipse moving?

Comment: @Clemens there is a fifth one in there ready to be used also :(. GayOnSteroids try sticking a breakpoint on the if statement and check what the values are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Four timer doesn't seems to be a good approach. I didn't see an obvious performance issue on single timer.

I have implemented your movements game using a single timer:

**Your Problem:**

1.You must added your **if statement** in each timer to check whenever needed

2.It's not your problem actually. `myCanvas's` Width and Height are Set into NaN (Not Defined) because you didn't set them. you must Use `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`

```
    Ellipse e1 = new Ellipse();
    DispatcherTimer t1;
    TimeSpan o = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10);
    Key Direction { get; set; } = Key.Space;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        t1 = new DispatcherTimer();
        t1.Interval = o;
        t1.Tick += T1_Tick;

        myCanvas.Children.Add(e1);
        e1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        Canvas.SetLeft(e1, 250);
        Canvas.SetTop(e1, 250);
        e1.Height = 75;
        e1.Width = 75;

        this.KeyDown += MainWindow_KeyDown;
        t1.Start();
    }

    private void T1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double X = Canvas.GetLeft(e1);
        double Y = Canvas.GetTop(e1);

        if (Direction == Key.Up) // Up
        {
            if (Y > 0)
                Canvas.SetTop(e1, Y - 10);
        }
        else if (Direction == Key.Left) // Left
        {
            if (X > 0)
                Canvas.SetLeft(e1, X - 10);
        }
        else if (Direction == Key.Right) // Right
        {
            if (X + e1.ActualWidth < myCanvas.ActualWidth)
                Canvas.SetLeft(e1, X + 10);
        }
        else if (Direction == Key.Down) // Down
        {
            if (Y + e1.ActualHeight < myCanvas.ActualHeight)
                Canvas.SetTop(e1, Y + 10);
        }
    }

    //MainWindow KeyDown
    private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Direction = e.Key;
    }
```

Comment: Better use a switch statement to avoid lengthy if/else chains.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things wrong with your code, most important is that your Tick handlers never compare the actual Left or Top value against any bounds.

Try this simplified version:

```
<Window ... KeyDown="WindowKeyDown">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Margin="40">
            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="200"
                     Width="75" Height="75" Margin="-37.5" Fill="Black"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

with a code behind with only one timer and a Tick handler that updates `Left` and `Top` according to a speed vector. The new position is checked against the lower bound zero, and upper bound `canvas.ActualWidth`/`canvas.ActualHeight`.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Vector speed = new Vector();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20) };
        timer.Tick += TimerTick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pos = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(ellipse), Canvas.GetTop(ellipse)) + speed;

        Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, Math.Min(Math.Max(pos.X, 0), canvas.ActualWidth));
        Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, Math.Min(Math.Max(pos.Y, 0), canvas.ActualHeight));
    }

    private void WindowKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        speed.X = 0;
        speed.Y = 0;

        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Left:
                speed.X = -10;
                break;
            case Key.Right:
                speed.X = 10;
                break;
            case Key.Up:
                speed.Y = -10;
                break;
            case Key.Down:
                speed.Y = 10;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

You may now also implement a different moving strategy by adding or subtracting components to/from the current speed vector:

```
private void WindowKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.Left:
            speed.X--;
            break;
        case Key.Right:
            speed.X++;
            break;
        case Key.Up:
            speed.Y--;
            break;
        case Key.Down:
            speed.Y++;
            break;
        default:
            speed.X = 0;
            speed.Y = 0;
            break;
    }
```